# Save a java.util.Date in a MySQL DB with Millisecond precision

Tags: jpa, mariadb

I would like to get ***millisecond precision*** in my MariaDB. After some research, I found that I needed to change the columnDefinition - so I did this in my entity:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "createdDate", columnDefinition = "DATETIME(3) NOT NULL")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private TimeStamp createdDate;

@PrePersist
void onPersist() {
    createdDate = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
}
```

The resulting SQL to create the column is:

```
`createdDate` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL
```

Now, in the DB the value has indeed 3 decimals:

```
2016-09-12 16:57:44.000
```

***... but they are always 000***

What did I do wrong, or what did I forget ?

**Edit: I tried without JAVA:**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `createdDate` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

And then:

```
INSERT INTO test (createdDate)
VALUES(current_timestamp())
```

Result:

```
2016-09-13 13:57:44.000
```

Comment: post the SQL invoked to INSERT

Comment: Can you use MySQL's `NOW(3)` instead of having Java generate the time?

Comment: This worked ! The date is created on persist in the java class. How can I achieve the same result using now(3) ?

Comment: Hey @Tim, we are running into exactly the same issue using a MariaDB-10.1, while the same code works fine with MySQL-5.7. Did you make any progress on this issue by yourself?

Comment: Hi - no I did not, I used another approach after all

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with MariaDB and date types. I've tried `org.joda.DateTime` and `java.util.time` types. Both, the server and the client code supported milliseconds correctly.

The problem was that **I was using [MySQL Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) instead of [MariaDB Connector](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/)**/J JDBC driver.

#### Background

In most situations using MariaDB with MySQL Connector works out well, but *I would never ever recommend this*. When I was searching for the issue I was debugging through Hibernate and Connector code and saw many feature detections that were based on the server version number instead of a real feature detection. The version numbering of course differs between MySQL and MariaDB. So there's a big probability that there are far more compatibility issues that are quietly ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem most probably comes from the fact that you mix Dates and Timestamps. Changing the `createdDate` type to `java.sql.Timestamp` should solve your issue.

Also, if your version of MySQL is prior to 5.6.4, `DateTime` won't let you save time fractions.

EDIT after OP's edit :

you are still mixing the Date Java type with Timestamp when you do this :

```
createdDate = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

Can you try `createdDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeInMilliseconds());` instead ?

Ideally you should use objects from a library like JodaTime to avoid such issues, but that's beyond the point of your question, just a tip :)

Ultimately, if this way of creating your Timestamp does not work, I would use the Timestamp type in DB instead of Datetime, but that's just trial and error as Datetime should work as well in your example.

Edit : 
excerpt from Oracle's Date API :

```
Date()
Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.
```

In which case using `System.currentTimeInMilliseconds()` shouldn't change the outcome - my bad.

To troubleshoot the problem, I'd start to create a date via SQL (without passing via Java objects) with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to make sure that the field can indeed contain decimal time precision.. If it is OK, verify the value in the Java object with a debugger.. Might give you a lead. If both contain milliseconds, I'd look at the usage of the annotations or start from a working sample.

Comment: I am using MariaDB 10.1 so it should be supported. I tried your suggestion but I stil get 2016-09-13 10:14:20.000. I edited my question. Any ideas ?

Comment: Ok great so we see that the problem lies (at least, but probably only hopefully) at the database side. Did you try with the TIMESTAMP datatype instead of DATETIME ? Can you thoroughly verify that your DBMS version is recent enough ?

Comment: Already tried that. MariaDB's doc says that milliseconds should work: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/datetime/

Comment: I must admit, my friend, that I am then out of options without having the environment in front of me

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance mode with the team advising migration to the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. The back-port of much of java.time to Java 6 & 7 ([ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)) is further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Answer (score 2):

To do this using pure JPA :

```
@Column(name="STMP", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP (6)")
private Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
```

Comment: this is not pure jpa, columnDefinition is SQL code, which is distribution dependent